# Opening a GDB database

Tags: python, firebird, kinterbasdb

I've been tasked with creating a script to convert Firebird databases to SQL. I was given to example files, one is a .FDB and one is a .GDB. Using the kinterbasdb library and Firebird Guardian 2.0, I was able to connect the the FDB file, but if I try the same code with the GDB file, I get an error message.

Code:

> filename = r'C:\TEMP\TEST_DB.GDB'
>
> user = 'sysdba'
>
> password = 'masterkey
>
> con = kinterbasdb.connect(dsn=filename, user=user, password=password)

Results:

> kinterbasdb.OperationalError: (-820, 'isc_attach_database: \n  unsupported on-disk structure for file C:\TEMP\TEST_DB.GDB; found 11.1, support 11.0')

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database has an On-Disk Structure (ODS) version 11.1, but your Firebird version only supports ODS 11.0 or lower. [ODS 11.0](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes207.html#apiods-ods) is Firebird 2, [ODS 11.1](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes210.html#rnfb20x-apiods-ods) is Firebird 2.1 and [ODS 11.2](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes252.html#rnfb25-apiods-ods) is Firebird 2.5.

You will need to install Firebird 2.1 or higher (I'd advise to use Firebird 2.5).

Answer (score -2):

-820, 'isc_attach_database error may be :

The version of the database file is larger than the library version.

The database file is corrupted. ( see this link: [repair a corrupt database](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq324/) )

[ibexpert documentation](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.Firebird21ErrorCodes)

[firebird documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/Firebird-1.5-ErrorCodes.pdf)

Comment: -820 is an error **group** that prevented connection. This specific errorcode simply means the database is not supported by the Firebird version.

Comment: Read the documentation before giving a negative vote

Comment: I know the cause of this error, and it isn't corruption of the file, hence my downvote.